# How do I allow a session to be created on domain.com that is accessible on sub.domain.com

Tags: php, session

How do I use session variables with domain.com and sub.domain.com?

This question has been asked several times but they lack an explanation I can understand. I have a user login on domain.com that when submitted creates session variables. When they are redirected to sub.domain.com those variables are inaccessible.

I have tried to edit htaccess and adding an ini_set to the top of my script. I have also tried to send domain.com to sub.domain.com's login script but the variable is only saved for domain.com. The htaccess technique I found here ended with server 500.

No only do I want a solution, but preferably if someone can explain why it is happening. I would like to know what the best practice for this is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has to do with how [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Scope_of_cookies) work. If the session cookie is out of scope, the browser won't even send it to the server.

Comment: @DavidG You can use $_GET, or $_POST to move variables from one domain to another instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share cookie between subdomain and domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain)

Comment: @cmprogram Putting the session ID in GET is not a good idea since it will then appear in the log files and is then susceptible to session hijacking. And POST wouldn't work if you want a simple link from one domain to the other.

Comment: @Mike you're absolutely right, GET is not particularly secure, but it performs the function that SESSION does not, which is why I included it. POST would be suitable as defined in the question, as it's about carrying values over rather than just a simple link.